# Cannot connect buttons to an event in PyQT

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt4

I have been trying to connect a button to a function and I get the following error:

```
QObject.connect(b1,SIGNAL("clicked()"),GetBestMatch)           
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QObject'
```

This is the connection code that I have written down that is giving the error:

```
QObject.connect(b1,SIGNAL("clicked()"),GetBestMatch)
```

I also tried to connect by the following code:

```
b1.clicked.connect(GetBestMatch)
```

and get the error:

```
b1.clicked.connect(GetBestMatch)         
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clicked'
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I am able to create a grid with labels and buttons but not connect the buttons to functions. This is the GUI Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
def MainWindow():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen_resolution = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
    width, height = screen_resolution.width(), screen_resolution.height()
    win = QWidget()
    win.adjustSize()
    grid=QGridLayout()
    grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)
    grid.setRowStretch(1, 1)
    grid.setRowStretch(5, 1)
    for i in range(0,5):
        for j in range(0,4):
            if i==0 and j==2:
               l1=grid.addWidget(QLabel("Choose an option:"),i,j, 2, 2)
            if i==2 and j==1:
                b1=grid.addWidget(QPushButton("Get Best Match"),i,j)
            elif i==2 and j==2:
                b2=grid.addWidget(QPushButton("Button 2"),i,j)
            elif i==2 and j==3:
                b3=grid.addWidget(QPushButton("Button 3"),i,j)
    b5=grid.addWidget(QLabel(""),3,4) 
    b4=grid.addWidget(QPushButton("Button 4"),2,4)         
    win.setLayout(grid)
    win.setGeometry(100,100,width//2,height//2,)
    win.setWindowTitle("Information on all tracking buses")
    win.show()
    win.setStyleSheet("""
    .QPushButton {
    height: 30px ;
    width: 20px ; 
    }
    .QLabel {
    qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;
    font-size:12pt
    }

    """)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def GetBestMatch():
    print ("HI")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow()
```

The layout works flawlessly without errors. Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QLayout.addWidget` does not return anything:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addWidget

So when you do

```
b1=grid.addWidget(QPushButton("Get Best Match"),i,j)
```

all is fine, but since `b1` is `None` - as the error messages clearly says.
So you'll need to spend two lines on this:

```
b1 = QPushButton("Get Best Match")
grid.addWidget(b1, i, j)
```

Then you should be good.

Comment: It woooorks! Thanks Sebastian! Hope you have a great day ahead :)

Comment: You're welcome :) please accept my answer , id it helped ;)

Comment: You mean upvote it? Sadly as I am new user, I am not "allowed" to upvote :(

Comment: I have a follow up question: If I create a new window in the GetBestMatch function, The window opens but closes immediately. Would you know why?
This is the code of the function:
def GetBestMatch():
 win1 = QWidget()
        win1.adjustSize()
        win1.setGeometry(100,100,width//2,height//2,)
        win1.setWindowTitle("Get Best Match")
        win1.show()